# Cannot recolor SVG favicon with gulp

Tags: svg, gulp

i'm trying to make simple favicon recolor by configurate and launch gulp module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-recolor-svg 
but it's still not working.

**(ERROR) Console returns: =(**

```
TypeError: firstColor.rgbArray is not a function
at colorDifference (/var/www/html.site.ru/src/node_modules/gulp-recolor-svg/lib/ColorMatcher.js:11:62)
```

**SVG**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 15 15" enable-background="new 0 0 15 15" xml:space="preserve">
    <path fill="#00ff00" d="M6.3,1.1v5.2H1.1c-0.7,0-0.7,0.5-0.7,1.2c0,0.7,0.1,1.2,0.7,1.2h5.2v5.2c0,0.7,0.5,0.7,1.2,0.7
        c0.7,0,1.2-0.1,1.2-0.7V8.7h5.2c0.7,0,0.7-0.5,0.7-1.2c0-0.7-0.1-1.2-0.7-1.2H8.7V1.1c0-0.7-0.5-0.7-1.2-0.7
        C6.8,0.4,6.3,0.5,6.3,1.1"/>
</svg>
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var color = require('color');
var recolorSvg = require('gulp-recolor-svg');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    return gulp
    .src('favicon.svg')
    .pipe(recolorSvg.GenerateVariants([recolorSvg.ColorMatcher(color('#00ff00'))], [
        {suffix: '--prod', colors: [color('#72982d')]},
        {suffix: '--dev', colors: [color('#8d67d2')]}
    ]))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('/'));
});
```

What's my mistake?

PS: I simplified my script for convenience of perception, I'm sorry if I made a mistake somewhere and here)

===========================================================================

**node_modules/gulp-recolor-svg/lib/RecolorSvg.js**

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.10.0
(function() {
  var Color, colorDifference, convert;

  Color = require("color");

  convert = require("color-convert");

  colorDifference = function(firstColor, secondColor) {
    var firstColorLabComponents, secondColorLabComponents, sumOfDifferencesSqaured;
    firstColorLabComponents = convert.rgb.lab.raw(firstColor.rgbArray());
    secondColorLabComponents = convert.rgb.lab.raw(secondColor.rgbArray());
    sumOfDifferencesSqaured = firstColorLabComponents.map(function(value, index) {
      return value - secondColorLabComponents[index];
    }).map(function(value) {
      return Math.pow(value, 2);
    }).reduce(function(sum, value) {
      return sum + value;
    }, 0);
    return Math.pow(sumOfDifferencesSqaured, 0.5);
  };

  module.exports = function(colorToMatch, maxDifference) {
    if (maxDifference == null) {
      maxDifference = 0.1;
    }
    return function(color) {
      var difference;
      difference = colorDifference(colorToMatch, color);
      return difference <= maxDifference;
    };
  };

}).call(this);
```

Comment: It seems like that line of code: `firstColor.rgbArray()` should look something like this: `rgbArray.call(firstColor)`

Am i right?

Comment: I think `.rgbArray()` just can't read color, because of the wrong format, but what format of the color it will need?

Comment: Still not resolved (

Comment: Still not solved

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue also.

Comment: This library uses Color, and the correct syntax at the time of writing is firstColor.rgb().array(). I have an issue open here https://github.com/richard-clark/gulp-recolor-svg/issues/4 and am forking and creating a pull request.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the exposed version of Color provided by the library, you shouldn't have a problem.

```
RecolorSvg.GenerateVariants(
    [RecolorSvg.ColorMatcher(RecolorSvg.Color("red"))],
    [
        { suffix: "--hover", colors: [ RecolorSvg.Color("red") ] },
        { suffix: "--active", colors: [ RecolorSvg.Color("red").darken(0.1) ] },
        { suffix: "--focus", colors: [ RecolorSvg.Color("cyan") ] },
        { suffix: "--disabled", colors: [ RecolorSvg.Color("#ccc") ] }
    ]
)
```

The error shown comes from the change in the Color module's API. The Color module that RecolorSvg uses is an older version.

Comment: Ok, i'll try it

Answer (score 0):

In ColorMatcher.js the line 11 has to be replaced like this:

`firstColorLabComponents = convert.rgb.lab.raw(firstColor.rgb().array());`

due to api change